# Removing digits from a string

Tags: c#, regex, sharepoint-2010, listitem

When I get the list value from the "Author" column on a list in SharePoint 2010, the following gets displayed:

2;#SP10Setup

Now the user that created that particular list item was "SP10Setup", now is there a simple way to remove "2;#" at the beginning of SP10Setup without affecting the digits in "SP10Setup"?

I have a method that currently is stripping out all digits

```
//method to strip out unnecessary digits
public static string RemoveDigits(string key)
{

return Regex.Replace(key, @"\d", "");
}
```

this is how I get the particular list item value:

```
string author = listItem["Author"].ToString();
```

this is how I removed unwanted digits and characters:

```
//calling the RemoveCharacter method
string noDigitsAuthor = RemoveDigits(author);
string cleanedupAuthor = noDigitsAuthor.Replace(";", "").Replace("#", "");
```

The result I get from this is "SPSetup", but ideally I would want the result to be "SP10Setup".

What would be the quickest and easiest way to achieve this...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not do it yourself.
Use [SPFieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup%28v=office.12%29.aspx) class

```
String author = "2;#SP10Setup";
SPFieldLookupValue lookup = new SPFieldLookupValue(author);
string cleanedupAuthor = lookup.LookupValue;
int authorId = lookup.LookupId;
```

so you will have:

```
cleanedupAuthor = "SP10Setup"
authorId = 2
```

Comment: wow this worked beautifully so simple and no need to mess around with regex, and replacing characters... Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression like `^\d*;#`. The `^` matches the start of the string, `\d*` says match zero or more digits and `;#` are literals.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always the same length you could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

first of al ';' and '#' are no digits. but you can take a loot at [Removing text in string using Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h.aspx)